# How to dynamically add and remove servlets within a servlet context in Jetty 9.4.x?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, osgi

I would like to add and remove servlets within a servlet context dynamically. I know how to add multiple servlet contexts dynamically using a ContextHandlerCollection. However, I need to do the same with multiple servlets within a context. Is it possible to add further servlets, once a servlet context is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlets can only be added, not removed.

See the various [`ServletContext.addServlet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) methods.

Note, however, that you can only change the `ServletContext` during [`ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) (see javadoc in [`ServletContext.addServlet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) for the `UnsupportedOperationException` throwable)

Comment: I think you are right. It does not really make sense within a context. The contexts already provide the possibility to handle some dynamic changes. Within a context endpoints should remain immutable. I wanted to share state (i.e. sessions) across contexts, wich is not suggested by Jetty. However, there are several other options on implementation side to solve this. For example, include a servlets within the context or share state information in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I did implement it several years ago in an [ECM](http://www.everit.org/ecm/index.html) component so servlets could be added and removed via ConfigAdmin settings without restarting Jetty itself in an OSGi environment.

As it was more than two years ago, I do not remember every detail, but you can check the code yourself. See the *updateServletsAndFilters()* function of *CustomServletHandler* class here: https://github.com/everit-org/jetty-server-ecm/blob/master/component/src/main/java/org/everit/jetty/server/ecm/internal/CustomServletHandler.java#L88

Some hints:

- In the *CustomServletHandler* subclass, I set a flag *ignoreUpdateMapping* while I update all mappings again otherwise the parent class would calculate the complete mapping after each iteration applying the new Servlet array
- I use _ReadWriteLock_s so during the update the *ServletHandler* will hold the new requests until the remapping is done

The function above is called from *updateServletHandlerWithDynamicSettings()* function of *ServletContextHandlerFactoryComponent* class (this is where the mappings, servlets and filters are precollected based on configuration): https://github.com/everit-org/jetty-server-ecm/blob/master/component/src/main/java/org/everit/jetty/server/ecm/internal/ServletContextHandlerFactoryComponent.java#L86

Comment: The rules with regards to Servlet/Filter add/remove/change within a ServletContext were *greatly* screwed down in Servlet 3.0+.   What you could get away with in Servlet 2.5 (i'm not breaking any rules) now result in Servlet Spec rules violations.   The CustomServletHandler approach you were using is deprecated now (btw), there are checks in the WebAppContext Configurations and even the ServletContext itself to invalid these kinds of updates now.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: I do not use any function that is marked as deprecated in the newest code of Jetty. The servlet spec cannot work in a dynamic environment indeed. The question was not about the spec. but about a dynamic solution based on Jetty-specific API.